# How much gluten should I add to maida flour for bread, and how?

Tags: bread

Flour you get in India needs additional gluten. My question is whether I need to add 1 teaspoon or 1 tablespoon of gluten to 1 cup of flour in a bread machine.

Also, how do I add it? Do I place the gluten along with the yeast in a hollow in the centre of the flour?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you'll likely get better results if you mix it together with the flour before you put it into the machine. As soon as gluten is exposed to moisture it will start to uncoil, mixing ahead of time will make sure it's evenly distributed when that happens.

As for how much to add I am not sure, it depends on the product and how much protein is in the flour already. I'd start with a teaspoon and add more if it is needed in future recipes.

Comment: Finally someone immune to the gluten paranoia (indyced).